# MVC web api with GET and POST Method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

how to execute MVC web api method with different name but type is GET and POST. i can't able to execute. it shows error. here is my code.

webapiconfig.cs

```
           config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
           name: "DefaultApi",
           routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
           defaults: new { action = "get", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
           );
```

Employee controller :

```
  [HttpGet]
  public string Test1()
  {
      return "this is a test1 string";
  }

  [HttpGet]
  public string Test2()
  {
      return "this is a test2 string";
  }
    [HttpPost]
    public string Test3()
    {
        return "this is a test3 string";
    }
```

i want to execute both post and get all this method in different scenario. how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to achieve this

- Specify different input parameters for methods with same Http Method (HttpGet/ HttPost/HttpPut).

Example -

```
 [HttpGet]
      public string Test1(string input)
      {
          return "this is a test1 string";
      }

[HttpGet]
  public string Test2()
  {
      return "this is a test2 string";
  }
```

- Specify explicit different routes for each of the method in Controller using multiple HttpGet.

  [HttpGet]
      [Route("~/mycontroller/action")]
      public string Test1(string input)
      {
             return "this is a test1 string";
      }

  ```
   [HttpGet]
      [Route("~/mycontroller/action2")]
      public string Test2()
      {
        return "this is a test2 string";
      }
  ```

Comment: struggling with formatting. Formatting behaving weired. Anyone can please do the formatting.